# C# connecting explicit FTP using system.net.FtpClient - certificate error

Tags: c#, ftp, ftp-client

I am using the System.Net.FtpClient
and I an trying to connect to a server (don't have access to the code in server).
when I connect using Winscp/Filezile I succeeded to connect.
however when I am using C# I am getting this exception:" 'The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.'"

not sure what am I doing wrong attaching my code and a photo when I connect using filezila

```
 System.Net.FtpClient.FtpClient _ftpClient = new System.Net.FtpClient.FtpClient();
            _ftpClient.Host = Host;
            _ftpClient.Port = 990;
            _ftpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(UserName, Password);                
            _ftpClient.SslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls;
            _ftpClient.EncryptionMode = System.Net.FtpClient.FtpEncryptionMode.Explicit;
            _ftpClient.Connect();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implementation is the same as fluent ftp:

```
_ftpClient.ValidateCertificate += 
_ftpClient_ValidateCertificate1;

private static void 
_ftpClient_ValidateCertificate(System.Net.FtpClient.FtpClient 
control, System.Net.FtpClient.FtpSslValidationEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Accept = true;
    }
```